# Is there a way to run multiple powershell scripts in different tabs in windows terminal?

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-terminal

I have a wrapper powershell script which runs a few more powershell scripts like this:

```
Start-Process PowerShell {-NoExit .\b.ps1}
Start-Process Powershell {-NoExit .\c.ps1}
Start-Process PowerShell {-NoExit .\d.ps1}
```

I use conemu to run the wrapper script and it opens all the other scripts in tabs.
Is there a way to do the same in the new windows terminal?

I tried this in the wrapper script:

```
wt new-tab PowerShell -c .\a.ps1
wt new-tab PowerShell -c .\b.ps1
wt new-tab PowerShell -c .\c.ps1
```

It opened separate windows for each and all of them errored out with command not found error.
Any other way to do this?

Comment: The ISE opens multiple sessions in different tabs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in the wrapper script:

```
wt.exe --window 0 new-tab --profile "Windows PowerShell" PowerShell -noexit -command .\a.ps1
wt.exe --window 0 new-tab --profile "Windows PowerShell" PowerShell -noexit -file .\b.ps1
wt.exe --window 0 new-tab --profile "Windows PowerShell" PowerShell -noexit -file .\c.ps1
```

Explanation taken mostly from [Using command line arguments for Windows Terminal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/terminal/command-line-arguments):

1. Syntax `--window <window-id>`: Launches the terminal in a specific window. Here `--window 0` always refers to the current `wt` window (see `wt -?`).
2. Syntax `new-tab --profile <profile-name> [command]`:

- `<profile-name>` could be installation dependent; I used `"Windows PowerShell"`.
- `[command]` (Square Brackets mean optionality): **`PowerShell -noexit -file .\c.ps1`**. Please note that I used either `-command` or `-file`, see `PowerShell -?`

Final note: consider using `--startingDirectory` parameter (or absolute paths to script files) because *facultative* `startingDirectory` in `WT` profile could target another destination than `.\` in `wt.exe` command…

Comment: Thanks!
I had to add the startingDir argument. So the command looks like:
`wt.exe --window 0 new-tab --profile "Windows PowerShell" -d . PowerShell -noexit -file a.ps1`

Answer (score 0):

You can make this a little simpler by just running this all as one command. Each `wt.exe` invocation is going to try and make a new window. You can chain multiple commands together however:

```
wt new-tab -d . -p "Windows PowerShell" powershell -noexit -file .\a.ps1 ; new-tab -d . -p "Windows PowerShell" powershell -noexit -file .\b.ps1 ; new-tab -d . -p "Windows PowerShell" powershell -noexit -file .\c.ps1
```

Or possibly, even simpler:

```
wt -d . powershell -noexit -file .\a.ps1 ; -d . powershell -noexit -file .\b.ps1 ; -d . powershell -noexit -file .\c.ps1
```

- you can use `nt` as a shorthand for `new-tab`. In fact, you can actually omit the subcommand entirely, and the Terminal will assume you meant `new-tab`
- you can omit `-p "Windows PowerShell"` if that's your default profile

Answer (score 0):

Here's what ended up working for me...

```
wt new-tab pwsh -noprofile -noexit  C:\pathToScript\script1.ps1 `; new-tab pwsh -noprofile -noexit  C:\pathToScript\script2.ps1 `; new-tab pwsh -noprofile -noexit  C:\pathToScript\script3.ps1 `;
```

It is important to escape the semicolon **`;** if your default shell is powershell also if you want to run the newer version of powershell **pwsh** is the executable to call.